# How take log output from a native library function in android

Tags: logging, android-ndk

I am developing an application which uses NDK, I want to take log outputs like we do in java android application code from a function that is declared and implemented in c library. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, these are the steps required to get log outputs from native side:

First, include necessary log header:

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

Then, define the log functions as follows for ease of use:

```
#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "some-tag", __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "some-tag", __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGE(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "some-tag", __VA_ARGS__))
```

Finally, whenever you would like to log, call the functions that you defined like you would use printf in regular C.

```
LOGI("someIntValue: %d", someIntValue);
LOGW("someCharValue: %c", someCharValue);
LOGE("someStringValue: %s", someStringValue);
```

Note that LOGI is used for regular log messages, LOGW is used for warnings and LOGE is used for error messages. You can also take a look at native-activity sample located inside NDK directory from which I learned how to log in NDK.